# Trying to make app for ebay seller in Python

Tags: python

Trying to make an app that subtracts all fees for items sold on Ebay.

```
NetSale = 0
ListFee = 0
PayPalFee = 0
ShippingFee = 0

def int_or_float(i):
    try:
        return int(i)
    except ValueError:
        return float(i)


NetSale = input("What is the Net Sale? ")
ListFee = input("What is the List Fee? ")
PayPalFee = input("What is the PayPal Fee? ")
ShippingFee = input("What is the Shipping Cost? ")

int_or_float(NetSale)
int_or_float(ListFee)
int_or_float(PayPalFee)
int_or_float(ShippingFee)

Profit = NetSale-ListFee

print(Profit)
```

When I run the app I get a type error because it is trying to subtract two strings. How do I make it so I can subtract these variables if they contain ints or floats?

Comment: You are returning the value from your `int_or_float()` function but not catching it, so you haven't replaced the strings stored in your four variables. Just change it to `NetSale = int_or_float(NetSale)`

Comment: What's the point of allowing both `int` and `float`? Wouldn't `float` by itself be sufficient?

Comment: I'm not sure.  I am very much a beginner.  Would float() work for all numbers not just decimals?

Answer (score 1):

In Python, passing immutable objects into a function will pass them by value and not by reference. You cast the value to an `int()` or `float()` in your `int_or_float()` function but don't catch it back in the main stream of your code. As a result, the `NetSale` variable is not modified by the `int_or_float()` function. It is still a string. Just catch it after the function call as such:

```
NetSale = int_or_float(NetSale)
ListFee = int_or_float(ListFee)
PayPalFee = int_or_float(PayPalFee)
ShippingFee = int_or_float(ShippingFee)
```

Comment: One little nit, passing objects into a function *never* passes them by value. It may appear it does, because reassigning them inside the function simply points the reference inside the function to a different object. Modifications to an object inside the function will always be visible outside the function, but that's a moot point when the object itself is immutable as `int` and `float` are.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer, I did some reading and now have a better grasp of how python handles arguments. I should have said that passing immutables ACT like passing by value, since operations to alter them are not valid, whereas passing mutables can seem like passing by reference until an assignment is made.

Answer (score 0):

The conversion to int/float can be done at the time of asking user input. The below code should do the trick.

```
NetSale = 0
ListFee = 0
PayPalFee = 0
ShippingFee = 0

def int_or_float(i):
    try:
        return int(i)
    except ValueError:
        return float(i)


NetSale = int_or_float(input("What is the Net Sale? "))
ListFee = int_or_float(input("What is the List Fee? "))
PayPalFee = int_or_float(input("What is the PayPal Fee? "))
ShippingFee = int_or_float(input("What is the Shipping Cost? "))

Profit = NetSale-ListFee

print(Profit)
```